# Meaning of the statement - du -sk * |sort -rn|head

Tags: disk-usage

I am facing trouble understanding the meaning of this Linux command:

```
du -sk * | sort -rn | head
```

I understand that du is used to display the disk usage but I'm facing trouble understanding the rest of the command. Can somebody please breakdown what's exactly happening here? Also can some good resources be suggested for studying complex linux commands in detail?

Comment: have you tried `man du`

Comment: Yes but the command as a whole seems very complex

Comment: A large part of the Unix philosophy is that programs should do one thing, very well. The entity you posted is a "pipeline" containing three commands. The shell which is running the pipeline resolves the data connections between the separate commands, each of which does part of the work, and has its own man page.

Comment: _Also can some good resources be suggested for studying complex linux commands in detail?_ https://explainshell.com

Comment: @LucaSchulz, mmh, that seems to give the man page explanations for e.g. `du -sk`, yes, but it doesn't tell what the difference between `du -s *` and just plain `du` is. (The latter would show each subdirectory, recursively, while `-s *` effectively just gives the first-level ones.) Also the description for `-k` there is just "like --block-size=1K", which isn't really that helpful because you then have to ask it again what `--block-size` is... And the description for that refers "SIZE format below", which is nowhere to be seen on that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a | b | c` runs `a`, `b` and `c` concurrently in separate processes with the stdout of one command connected to the stdin of the next one via a pipe.

Here, `a` is `du -sk *`. `*` is expanded by the shell to the names of the non-hidden files in the current directory sorted lexically (and if there's no non-hidden files, either abort the command with an error or expands to a literal `*` depending on the shell).

Here, if any of the files had a name starting with `-`, that would be treated as an option by `du`, so the correct syntax would have been: `du -sk -- *`, the `--` making sure that anything past it is not treated as an option.

`-k` is to get disk usages in kibibyte (1024 bytes, the default being 512 byte units in standard `du` implementations¹). `-s` is to summarize the disk usage of each file (for those of type *directory*, it does not give a detailed about all the subdirectories).

So it will print the disk usage (cumulative for those of type directory) of all the non-hidden files in the current directory with the number of kibibyte followed by the file name on the same line (though beware that file names may be made of more than one line).

With many `du` implementations, if some of the arguments refer to the same file (hardlinks) or the same file is found in more than one directory, then only the disk usage of the first occurrence will be accounted in the output.

`sort -rn` `sort`s the *lines* of its input `n`umerically in `r`everse, so assuming none of the file names contain newline characters, will sort the files / dirs from the largest to the smallest (in terms of disk usage).

`head` (short for `head -n 10`) discards all but the first 10 lines of the output of `sort`.

A more correct version, with GNU implementations of those utilities would be:

```
du -skl0 ./* | sort -zk1,1rn | head -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Where `-l` forces all hardlinks to be accounted, `-0`/`-z` outputs/processes records NUL-delimited so it works better for file names containing newline characters (and the `./` prefix can give you an indication of where each file name starts in the output for those that contain newlines in addition to avoiding problems with filenames starting with `-`); using `sort -k1,1rn` instead of `sort -rn` changes the behaviour in case of ties (two files with same disk usage), avoiding sorting the ties lexically in reverse.

---

<sup>¹ for GNU `du`, the default is kibibytes, though can be overwritten with environment variables including `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, `DU_BLOCK_SIZE`, `BLOCK_SIZE`, `BLOCKSIZE`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It is using the pipe construct, which allows the output of one command to feed in as input the the following command.

```
du -sk * |sort -rn|head
```

starts 3 commands

```
du -sk *
```

Which runs the disk usage command `du` output in kilobytes (`-k`), including sub-directories, output only a subtotal (`-s`) is sent as input to

```
sort -rn
```

Which will sort, treating each line key as numeric, in reverse order (decending), output is sent to next command.

```
head
```

which as default will output the first 10 lines only.